# Ruby on Rails Passing Parameter In URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

This is probably a very simple fix but I've been unable to find an answer just yet.

My application has orders and tasks. Orders have many tasks. When a user clicks new task in the show order view, it passes the order.id:

```
<%= link_to "New Task", new_task_path(:order_id=> @order.id) %>
```

The url shows:

```
/tasks/new?order_id=1
```

I just don't know how to extract this and use it in my form? I have tried:

```
<%= f.text_field :order_id, :value => @order_id %>
```

But it's not working.

Comment: Typo in `:value => @order_id`. Shouldn't it be `:value => @order.id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [can do](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render):

```
<%= f.text_field :order_id, :value => params[:order_id] %>
```

Alternately, capture the value (with `params`) [in the controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#parameters) and assign it to `@order_id` there.

Comment: Better make it a hidden field though: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/hidden_field

Comment: @Jenny Please see my answer. This is absolutely the **wrong way** to do this in Rails.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing this wrong, which is a *big deal* in Rails where convention-over-configuration is such an important ideal.

If an order has many tasks, your route should look like this:

```
/orders/:order_id/tasks/new
```

And your routes should be configured thusly:

```
resources :orders do
  resources :tasks
end
```

You should *[almost] never* find yourself passing around record ids in the query string. In fact, you should almost never find yourself using query strings at all in Rails.

Comment: Nested resources aren't always appropriate. Some people think they're *never* appropriate, but I won't start that argument here. Even if you think they're *sometimes* appropriate, it's not 100% clear from the question that orders to tasks is an ownership rather than association relationship. I agree that this is a good *option*, but I object to calling other options "absolutely the **wrong way** to do this in Rails," to quote your other comment. Consider, e.g., if an "order" is an optional field on a task.