# fullcalendar filter results from json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, fullcalendar

I'm fairly new to ruby and I'm trying to set up a calendar of room viewings.

So far I have got a calendar to show up, but it is displaying all viewings that have been made. I want to filter it down so it only shows viewings of a certain `room_id`.

I've searched for hours for a solution for this but can't seem to get anything working.

The calendar is initialized in viewings.coffee with the following:

```
$(document).ready ->
  $("#calendar").fullCalendar(
    events: '/viewings.json'
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
    slotDuration: '00:60:00'
    height: 620
  )
```

and the data for the calendar is populated from the viewings table, using `jbuilder` as so: (`viewings/index.json.builder`)

```
json.array!(@viewings) do |viewing|
  json.extract! viewing, :id, :room_id, :user_id, :start_time, :end_time, :notes
  json.title viewing.user.name
  json.start viewing.start_time
  json.end viewing.end_time
  json.url viewing_url(viewing, format: :html)
end
```

from what I can gather I need to use `clientEvents` to filter down the Events in the calendar, but I can't work out where or how this need to be coded.

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to look up and generate the `@viewings` variable based on the `room_id`, so you need something like this:

```
@viewings = Viewing.where(room_id: 1)
```

That would make `@viewings` get populated with only those viewings with that `room_id` (of 1 in this case). Presumably you'd want to pass that `room_id` as a parameter though based on which room the user selects in the web UI.

Comment: Thank you! after so many wasted hours, I can't believe the solution was so simple.

Comment: Another way to say this is:  you are asking the system for "'/viewings.json".  How is the system supposed to know, from this url alone, that you only want a subset of viewings returned in the data?

Comment: Exactly. The above solution works in terms of filtering the data now. I now need to come up with a way of passing the parameter (room_id) through, depending on which rooms/show.html.erb is being accessed.

Comment: any ideas for how to pass through a room_id, ideally from a collection_select?

Comment: One direct way would be to just pass it as a param, so your URL would look like this `/viewings.json?room_id=1` and you would capture it with `params[:room_id]`. If you want something a little cleaner, you could make it part of your routes, so say have the URL be `"/room/1/viewings.json"`. See the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info on routes. For the `collection_select` aspect, it may be better to just post a new question with the details of it since we are somewhat straying from the original question.

Comment: Thanks @draffensperger  I'm still not really sure how to pass in the params but I've got a while to figure this one out, but if anyone can help clarify things it would be a great help!

Comment: This question explains passing parameters: [Ruby on Rails Passing Parameter in URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6306690/ruby-on-rails-passing-parameter-in-url)